# VideoView onErrorListener

Tags: android, android-videoview

Is it possible to handle an error in the `OnErrorLisenter` for the `VideoView` such that it continues playing the video.  I've tried the following code and it just freezes.  This problems seems common to honeycomb 3.2 where every 5-10 minutes it has a problem with the video stream and crashes.

The error handler below causes the video to freeze for about 1 minute after which it starts playing again.  I've also tried reinitializing the video view which works but I can't seem to capture the current position of the video that was playing in order to seek to that position and continue playing from the position it had an error.

```
vw.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {           
            if (showUri != null) {
                Log.v("ShowViewerActiity", String.valueOf(mp.getCurrentPosition()));

            }
            mp.start();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: errorlistner is use for when any error come..and when error come why are you add `mp.start()`

Comment: Samir - i'm having problems with the videoview stopping about 10 minutes into playing on android 3.2 devices.  The video plays fine without error on all other versions.  I'm trying to patch this problem and have the video continue where it left off.